# Which documentations / pdfs are worth printing for reference as programmer

Tags: windows, linux, programming-languages, documentation

I have just printed and binded Advanced Bash Scripting guide . it had 800 pages.
and It was really worth of that.

Are there more like that which are worth to be printed and binded to keep aside ofr reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are very new to a programming language, I don't have a tutorial for you. But what is always handy, when you are programming in a certain language, is a cheat sheet. This site has many cheat sheets for each programming language:
http://www.cheat-sheets.org/

You should check it out.